# Add fee taxes on quote

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, tax, quote

I'm facing issue about taxes on quotation. I'm trying add fee taxes on quotation, but all attempt are unsuccessful.

I'm try use this

```
$address->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
$address->setTaxRate($taxRate);
```

To collect total and do a calculation.

```
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found. It was to take the request generated and create a new calculation rule for this exception value that comes from the marketplace that ultimately makes up the value of the product.

In order to facilitate the work of the financial sector has to generate the NF with all explicit taxes on it.

I am a willingness to clarify more about.